# executable jar Could not find or load main class

Tags: java

I've been struggling with this common error and just can't resolve it. This application is composed of multiple packages and runs fine within JCreator (at the moment I need to use this IDE rather than Eclipse).

My manifest file is here (there are 2 blank lines at the end):

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.6.0_45 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Main-Class: C:\COMPILE\MyProjects\douwe\classes\dykstra\dplus\main\DPMain
```

I wrote a bat file to create the jar:

> jar -cvfm DPlus.jar C:\COMPILE\MyProjects\douwe\classes\MANIFEST.MF
>   C:\COMPILE\MyProjects\douwe\classes\dykstra\dplus\main*.class 
>   C:\COMPILE\MyProjects\douwe\classes\dykstra\dplus\library*.class
>   C:\COMPILE\MyProjects\douwe\classes\dykstra\dplus\command*.class
>   C:\COMPILE\MyProjects\douwe\classes\dykstra\dplus\file*.class
>   C:\COMPILE\MyProjects\douwe\classes\dykstra\dplus\file\display*.class
>   C:\COMPILE\MyProjects\douwe\classes\dykstra\dplus\command*.class
>   C:\COMPILE\MyProjects\douwe\classes\dykstra\dplus\file*.class
>   C:\COMPILE\MyProjects\douwe\classes\dykstra\dplus\file\display*.class
>   C:\COMPILE\MyProjects\douwe\classes\dykstra\dplus\gui*.class
>   C:\COMPILE\MyProjects\douwe\classes\dykstra\dplus\gui*.class
>   C:\COMPILE\MyProjects\douwe\classes\dykstra\dplus\job*.class
>   C:\COMPILE\MyProjects\douwe\classes\dykstra\dplus\job*.class
>   C:\COMPILE\MyProjects\douwe\classes\dykstra\dplus\types*.class
>   C:\COMPILE\MyProjects\douwe\classes\dykstra\dplus\util*.class

When I try to execute with the command

> C:\COMPILE\MyProjects\douwe\classes>java -jar DPlus.jar

I always get the error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class C:\COMPILE\MyProjects\douwe\classes\dykstra\dplus\main\DPMain
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Usually this error is due to `MANIFEST.MF` if the'res no application's entry point has been set. 
Your manifest file should have this line of code

```
Main-Class: YourPackage.DPMain
```

Alternatively, you can do the following.

```
java -cp .;app.jar YourPackage.DPMain
```

Answer (score 0):

In my implementation, there are something different from yours, you can refer:

(1) The folder(before compressed) structure
you need to add a META-INF folder and put your `MANIFEST.MF` in it

[image]

(2) The content in your `MANIFEST.MF` 
I think your should use the package format instead of a folder tree format:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.loadtest.mgr.LoadTestStarter
```